# Objective C - remove drawing

Tags: objective-c

I've been using the code below to draw on an UIView

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.5);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

So that part works.
Now how do I clear my drawing? Most of the example just shows the drawing. Having a hardtime finding keyword to google.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [CGContextClearRect](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClearRect)?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

it sends the message `drawRect:` to the view.